# nrpe: Connection has taken too long to establish. Exiting

Tags: nrpe

It has been several months that I have setup `nrpe` and it was working well till yesterday, there is a continuous log output from `nrpe` saying:

> nrpe: Connection has taken too long to establish. Exiting...

and the services are periodically flapping from `ok` to `critical`
(CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 20 seconds).

Can you please help me to figure this out.

Comment: Nothing specific to nrpe, I would say; probably general network problems, causing *all* network connections to periodically fail.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I give you a stupid answer but sometime helps...
If nothing it's changed sometimes case like this happening for DNS  resolution problems or search dns suffix mistake or you have configured 2 DNS and the first one dosen't  work so you have to wait the timeout expired.

My best!